# Naming a class property in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, naming-conventions

I have a data in mongodb collection

```
  "2021": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "entity": "FA3T1",
      "value": 16,
      "remarks": "GOODRICH ACTUATION SYSTEMS SAS"
    }
  ]
```

Can anyone please suggest what would be the name of the class to be mentioned in c# for the property so as to deserialize the data from mongodb

I have tried the below option:

```
_2021
```

Answer (score 0):

`2021` is not a valid property name in C#; you can use a valid property name and mark the property with a `BsonElement` attribute to connect it with the corresponding BSON property, e.g.:

```
[BsonElement("2021")]
public IEnumerable<MyType> Data2021 { get; set; }
```

However, if there is a `2021` element in BSON, there might also be a `2020` and `2022`. In this case, you could have a look at dictionary serialization that allows to fill a dictionary like with keys for the years and values for the corresponding data. You can use the [`BsonDictionaryOptions`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Attributes_BsonDictionaryOptionsAttribute.htm) attribute in this case.